# Different implementations of Partial in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, babel-loader

I am trying to use Partial of typescript by following the examples of [Fast-dna repo](https://github.com/microsoft/fast-dna/blob/master/packages/fast-components-react-base/src/button/button.tsx) and i notice that in my repo I have a different implementation of `Partial`

For them `Partial` is defined as

[image]

For me it is coming as

[image]

The only difference i see is that they are using babel and i am not.
Is this the reason?

But i still don't get how there can be two different implementations ?

I am using Create react app with typescript template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not two different implementations of `Partial` there is just one, the difference comes from typescript settings.

When you have `strictNullChecks` turned on, typescript automatically adds to the type of optional properties, a `| undefined` (union with `undefined`). This makes sense as under strict null checks, ts keeps track of `undefined` and `null` as separate types, and optional properties can always be `undefined`. If this option is turned off there is no separate tracking of `undefined` and this it is not added.

You can see this in the playground as well:

With [strictNullChecks:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAHlC8UAKBDATsAligNgHgG8BfAPiA)
[image]

Without [null checks:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictNullChecks=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAHlC8UAKBDATsAligNgHgG8BfAPiA)

[image]